# deeper merge_behaviour for hiera 5 not working, but working in hiera 3

Tags: puppet, hiera

Deep merger not working in hiera 5.

I use `merge_behavior: deeper` in main hiera.yaml version 3 so it will merge all hiera data where it find it, but now I have upgrade to version 5, and found out the merge behavior not working?

```
:merge_behavior: deeper
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Puppet has [documentation for upgrading from Hiera 3 to Hiera 5](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_migrate_v3_yaml.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official Puppet [documentation for upgrading from Hiera 3 to Hiera 5](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_migrate_v3_yaml.html):

> These have no equivalent support in a version 5.  If you’d like to
>   learn about how Hiera 5 supports deep hash merging, see [Merging data
>   from multiple sources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_merging.html).

I ended up using the `lookup()` function in puppet files in place of the `hiera_hash()` function. something like this.

from

```
hiera_hash( 'firewall::firewalld::zones', {} )
```

to

```
lookup( { 'name' => 'firewall::firewalld::zones',
                                'merge' => { 
                                  'strategy' => 'deep',
                                  'knockout_prefix' => '--',
                                }, 
                                'default_value' => {} 
                      })
```

Comment: If you post a verbatim quotation from someone else, then *do* kindly indicate that you're doing so, and provide proper attribution.

Comment: Properly attributing quoted text has three main elements: (1) indicating *which* text or other material is being attributed to another party; (2) indicating, with adequate specificity, *from where* the material was drawn; and (3) indicating *to whom* that material should be credited.  I have edited your answer to show one way to do this.  Under no circumstance does upvoting a comment serve as any kind of attribution.

Comment: As for the actual data lookup, what you present is a good substitute for `hiera_hash()`.  You might also consider, however, that Hiera 5 recognizes metadata in your data sources that tell it what kind of lookup to perform by default, on a key by key basis.  This allows you to get a hash-merge lookup by default, for instance, including getting that form of lookup for automatic class-parameter lookup where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation [Hiera: Merging data from multiple sources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_merging.html#deep) says:

> Note: Hiera 5’s deep merge is equivalent to Hiera 3’s “deeper” merge.

You can define lookup rules in some YAML config:

```
lookup_options:
  "^firewall::(.*)":
    merge:
      strategy: deep
```

using `puppet lookup --explain needle` from CLI might be helpful in understanding what's going on:

```
$ puppet lookup --explain firewall::firewalld::zones
Searching for "lookup_options"
  Global Data Provider (hiera configuration version 5)
    Using configuration "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hiera.yaml"
    Merge strategy hash
      Hierarchy entry "Defaults"
        Path "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/hieradata/default.yaml"
          Original path: "default.yaml"
          Found key: "lookup_options" value: {
            "^firewall::(.*)" => {
              "merge" => {
                "strategy" => "deep"
              }
            }
          }
      Merged result: {
        "^firewall::(.*)" => {
          "merge" => {
            "strategy" => "deep"
          }
        }
      }
  ...
```

You can replace `hiera_hash( 'firewall::firewalld::zones', {} )` by:

```
lookup('firewall::firewalld::zones', Hash, {'strategy' => 'deep'}, {})
```

or with predefined `lookup_options` you'd end up with simple code like:

```
lookup('firewall::firewalld::zones')
```